# svelte-i18n : How to format a message with @html

Tags: html, svelte, svelte-i18n

I'm trying to display a text using a variable in a translation file like this:

```
{@html ($_("page.faq.frequent_questions", { values: { numberOfQuestions: '4' } }))}
```

and here is my json file:

```
{   
    "page": {
        "faq": {
            "frequent_questions": "<span>{numberOfQuestions} frequently asked </span>questions"
        }
    }
}
```

But nothing is displayed...

How can I solved this problem ?

Thanks for the help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with `@html` or the code shown. You need to make sure to set up everything correctly.

1. Register the dictionary/dictionaries
2. Init the locale
3. Wait for locale to have loaded

Using your data, here is fully working example:

```html
<script>
  import { register, init, waitLocale, getLocaleFromNavigator, _ } from 'svelte-i18n';

  register('en', () => Promise.resolve({   
      "page": {
          "faq": {
              "frequent_questions": "<span>{numberOfQuestions} frequently asked </span>questions"
          }
      }
  }));
  init({ initialLocale: getLocaleFromNavigator(), fallbackLocale: 'en' });
</script>

{#await waitLocale() then}
  <p>
    {@html ($_("page.faq.frequent_questions", { values: { numberOfQuestions: '4' } }))}
  </p>
{/await}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/17133ff11caa46c28dd77d1b37d525b3?version=3.48.0)

Comment: It was just a bad usage of quote in the translation...